# d3 selections not passing data down as expected with .join()

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6, selection

I have been using the d3 v5 .join update pattern. It's great, but I have a situation in my code where the data is not being passed down as expected and I am at a loss for what is going wrong. My code looks like this :

```
let binnedWrap = wrap.selectAll('.attr-wrap').data(sortedBins).join('g').attr('class', d=> d.key + ' attr-wrap');
binnedWrap.attr('transform', (d, i)=>  'translate(0,'+(i * (height + 5))+')');

let label = binnedWrap.append('text').text(d=> d.key).attr('y', 40).attr('x', 80).style('text-anchor', 'end');

let branchGroup = binnedWrap.selectAll('g.branch-bin').data(d=> {
    ///THIS IS RIGHT
    console.log('data before the branch bins',d);
    return d.branches}).join('g').classed('branch-bin', true);

branchGroup.attr('transform', (d, i)=> 'translate('+(100 + branchScale(i))+')');
```

This works as expected. The data that consoles is correct and it creates a group classed 'branch-bin' for each branch element in `d.branches`

BUT- when I attempt to use the branch data within each of the 'branch-bin' group, I am not getting the expected `d.branches` data:

```
 let continDist = branchGroup.filter(f=> f.type === 'continuous');

var lineGen = d3.line()
.y((d, i)=> {
    console.log('y',d, i)
    let y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 16]).range([0, height]);
    return y(i); 
})
.x(d=> {
    let x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 100]);
    return x(Object.entries(d).length - 2); 
});
//THIS IS RIGHT//
console.log(continDist.data())

continDist.append('path').data((d, i)=> {
    console.log('supposed to be data in d branch', d, i);
    return lineGen(d.bins)});
```

The output looks the same as the above console. The path is not being passed the branch data.

[image]

Any idea what is going on here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of using

`continDist.append('path').data((d, i)=>lineGen(d.bins));`

instead of `continDist.append('path').attr('d', (d, i)=>lineGen(d.bins));`

after assigning `d` as an `attr` of path it worked as expected.